# Azure Function give req body parameters default values

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a HTTP trigger Azure Function with about 10 parameters in the request body, strings ints and booleans.
When called not all parameters will have values. In the code I need to check if one is empty or not, and then do different actions depending on the result.
Problem is that empty req parameters give errors.
I'd like the string parameters to be "" when they are empty, the ints 0 and booleans false, but I'm pretty new to Azure and don't know how to give them default values.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is probably a language-specific question and not an Azure Functions question. What language are you working in? And what do you mean by "give errors"? I may be misunderstanding your question, but here's a C# example you may want to look at that behaves differently based on whether or not a req parameter is there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---c-script-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using *default* values in the host.json file.

```
"queues": {
        "description": "Configuration settings for 'queue' triggers.",
        "type": "object",

        "properties": {
            "maxPollingInterval": {
                "description": "The maximum interval in milliseconds between queue polls.",
                "type": "integer",
                "default": 1000
            },

            "batchSize": {
                "description": "The number of queue messages to retrieve and process in parallel (per job function).",
                "type": "integer",
                "maximum": 32,
                "minimum": 1,
                "default": 16
            },

            "maxDequeueCount": {
                "description": "The number of times to try processing a message before moving it to the poison queue",
                "type": "integer",
                "default": 5
            },

            "newBatchThreshold": {
                "description": "The threshold at which a new batch of messages will be fetched. The default is batchSize/2.",
                "type": "integer"
            },

            "visibilityTimeout": {
                "description": "The visibility timeout that will be applied to messages that fail processing.",
                "pattern": "^\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d$",
                "default": "00:00:00"
            }
        }
    }
```

Schema reference: http://json.schemastore.org/host

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Marie, Azure Functions has an example for how to [map a request body to a POCO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---c-script-example). The fields on this POCO will be populated by deserializing the request body JSON. If you include properties of type `string`, `bool`, and `int` on this POCO, they should be populated by their respective default values if you don't include those fields in the request body.